# How to generate Scikit-Learn Gaussian Process regression with 2D input, 1D output

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian, training-data

I have been looking for the answer to my question for quite a while. No Luck so far :(. I will my question as simple as possible. For the simplicity I only have a 2D input(it will eventually grow). Lets say I am using two variables (feature : Vehicle Odometer measurement, New Car Price) to predict a value of the car (target : Old car price) How can I train sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor to predict what I am looking for.

```
from sklearn import gaussian_process


X_train = np.array(X).reshape((-1, 2)).astype(int)

y_train = np.array(y).reshape(-1,1).astype(int)

GPR = gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor(normalize_y = False,n_restarts_optimizer = 3)

GPR.fit(X_train,y_train)
#creating random points for testing the data
X_test_Odometer = np.linspace(0, 268000, 1000)[:, None]
X_test_Price = random.sample(range(5000, 13000), 1000)
X_test = np.column_stack((X_test_Odometer,X_test_Price)).astype(int)

GPR.predict(X_test)
```

This prediction doesnot work at all. I do not know whether I need to customize a kernel. If yes, I do not know how to. I am new to scikit and any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work at all"? Please be specific.

Comment: It gives me either just one integer for all the test inputs or 0 for all the inputs (depends what kernel I use)

Comment: Maybe GaussianProcessRegressor is not suitable for your data. Try other available algorithms.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: The choice of an algorithm depends on the data you have. As far as I can see, you're testing your model on random points. How do you expect it to work?